# XML Parsing in hadoop/pig

Tags: java, xml, apache-pig, hadoop2

I want to extract data from large xml, for ex. via xpath, and process it (data select, grouping). Is it simpler way, than described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32608540/xml-parsing-hadoop-mapreduce)? For ex., via Apache Avro?
Or, maybe, it will be better to do it [in Pig](http://hadoopgeek.com/apache-pig-xml-parsing-xpath/)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read XML using XPath in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811001/how-to-read-xml-using-xpath-in-java)

Comment: That is exactly stays in link "this question"

Comment: Then you should be posting your question in that topic, as you are more likely to get a response to it.

Comment: My fault. Your and my links are different. But question you've mentioned is not copy of current one.